# How does Iris' Axew actually stay in her hair?

Tags: anime, pokemon

In [Pokémon: Best Wishes!](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon:_Best_Wishes!) / [Pokémon the Series: Black & White](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_the_Series:_Black_%26_White), how does [Iris'](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Iris_(anime)) [Axew](https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Iris_(anime)#Axew) not fall out of her hair?

Is it because of Axew's small claws? Or because of how long they've been training together at tree jumping that Axew has become environmentally normalized in balancing in Iris' hair? Or is it just supposed to be a anime thing?

Is there a canon explanation in the anime for how Axew stays in Iris' hair?

Comment: Can you explain what movie/book/game your talking about

Comment: @Makoto I believe it's the *Pokémon: Best Wishes* anime.

Answer (score 1):

Iris has very long hair and the tie that she uses seems to create a natural hollow for her Axew to sit in.

[image]

Axews are perfectly capable of scaling trees and sitting on branches, so clearly they have some climbing ability and natural balance.

[image]